# Move class into another class by ReSharper

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-5.1

I have a **non-nested** class `WillBeNestedClass` and another class `NestBox`.
Now I want to move class `WillBeNestedClass` into class `NestBox` as a nested class. So `WillBeNestedClass` will be nested in class `NestBox`.

Is there a refactoring in VS or ReSharper that can do that moving and that automatically updates all references to nested class (from `WillBeNestedClass` to `NestBox.WillBeNestedClass`)?

Comment: See [issue RSRP-44434](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-44434).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is no such quick-action or refactoring available in ReSharper by default. Maybe there is some plugin that allows this - or you could try and create your own. I'm sure it'd be appreciated by more developers.

Available out of the box are:

- Move to folder
- Move to namespace
- Move to separate file

I did, as you, attempt to use Move to namespace and input a type but that dog wouldn't fly.